# Git-SVN: how can i merge branch to trunk?

Tags: merge, git-svn

I am working on a git-svn project with two branches, lets call them

```
trunk
branches/foo
```

How can i merge branches/foo to trunk?

they both have the latest update

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is inadvisable to merge two SVN branches via Git.  If in Git you merge from your `branches/foo` clone to your `trunk` clone and then managed to successfully push back to SVN, the files would be correctly updated on `trunk`, but SVN wouldn't be aware that it's the result of a merge - no merge-tracking information will be updated in SVN.

In fact it gets more complicated than that - when you merge between two Git branches that are both tracking remote SVN repos, git-svn can get really confused and it's very easy to mess up your repository.  This is because git-svn looks back through your Git log to find the SVN tracking information, and if it finds a merge then it won't necessarily head down the branch you expect.  So even if you've merged from `branches/foo` into `trunk` and you're now on trunk, it's possible that a `dcommit` would push back to `branches/foo`.

Better to switch back to your regular SVN tools to do merges and just use git-svn for development.

Answer (score 0):

Another roof option could be next:

checkout your trunk branch # git checkout -b trunk git-svn-trunk

and cherry-pick dev commits into trunk branch,

i prefer pick one by one and solve conflict slowly

after that you have a 2 branches with the same commits
maybe do you want remove dev branch and create a new dev branch from trunk branch,
now this branch (new dev branch) has a correct  git-svn reference to your svn trunk...

keep recommendations write by @simonp answer

i hope this help to you